# Entity Framework 4.1 Link table query how to?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

I'm relatively new to the Entity Framework and I'd like to do a query that includes a link table.  Any suggestions on how to do a basic join query using LINQ?

Entity Structure

**News**
NewsID

**CommunityNews**
CommunityID
NewsID

**Community**
CommunityID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're generating the context from a database using the EDMX editor, and you have the appropriate foreign key constraints set up, you should be able to just add those three tables to the context, and it will create a many-to-many mapping between `News` and `Community`.

```
var newsForCommunity = context.News.Where(
    n => n.Communities.Any(
        c => c.CommunityId == communityId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The EDMX edit does show the navigation properties.  So this is what I've got so far. _context.NewsViews.Where(n => n.NewsCommunities.Any(c => c.Community_ID == communityID);  But the communityID seems to break it.  Where does the communityID come from?

Comment: @Eric: This was simply an example showing how you might query across linked tables. `communityId` in the example is just a variable. You can replace it with the ID of some community that you're trying to get news for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can write the query:

```
var newsForCommunity = 
(from c in context.Communities
 from n in c.News
 where c.CommunityID == communityID
 select n.NewsID
).ToList();
```